# iOS writing unit tests for a library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I'm writing a library that adds syntactic sugar to native iOS framework functions.  As such, I am extending native types such as NSString and NSArray.  For example:

```
@implementation NSString (NPB)

-(BOOL) includesCharsInString: (NSString *)charsInString
{
    NSCharacterSet *charset  = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charsInString];
    return [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charset].location != NSNotFound;
}

@end
```

In my test framework I include the extended .h files and have the library as a target dependency, and also link against it.  However, when I write a test against the library, the tests fail with "unrecognized selector sent to ..." error.

If I include the appropriate .m file in the compile sources list, then it works fine.  But if I'm linking against the library, why would I need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the linker can't find any usage of category code, they are, by default, stripped when linking against libraries.  In your build settings, add -ObjC to your linker flags.